# Allowing user to purchase consumable in-app-purchase over tier 60

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, applet

So recently I got an app rejected for having a consumable in-app-purchase over tier 60. Apparently, this is not allowed (although not mentioned in their guidelines).

In cases where as an app developer, I want to sell credits for example, at a value of $500, what is the recommended way to do this?

Making these products "non-consumable" would effectively mean that a user would only be to purchase this product once, which is why I used consumables in the first place.

Any ideas / anyone run into this issue before?

Thanks!

Comment: The user will need to purchase multiple instances of a lower tier product, for example 2 x $250 product.

Comment: @Paulw11 You can't go over $99 (Tier 60) - but I've seen apps like Cameo (cameo.com) allow for $1000 purchases...how do they do so?

Comment: They may have been approved in the past. Just because something has been approved in the past or approved for another app it doesn't mean it will be approved in the future or for your app. You need to work with Apple.

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1: For the consumable product you have to set the price less than $99.99. You can sell your product in parts as this is consumable so won’t effect your product value.
For example:

if you want to sell 2000 Diamonds in $500

then can set 500 Diamonds in $99.99

Solution 2: If you still want to fix your preferred amount then you can request for this on resolution centre and discuss your scenarios with Apple Store.